# Why my Google Static Map API doesn't show custom marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google map static API on my website. The map works properly but I failed to make the custom marker works.

```
<img class="map-venue-detail" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&markers=icon:localhost/assets/imagetest.png%7C{{ object.company.latitude }},{{ object.company.longitude }}&zoom=15&size=768x400&key=MY_KEY">
```

The crazy part is, when I try using the example marker from the Google Map Static (`https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/images/star.png`) then the map works with the custom google star marker but as soon as I use my `PNG` it doesn't work anymore.

I saw that some people suggested the resolution issue. But I also have tried to save the google marker image to my localhost and use that image (so instead of pointing to `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/images/star.png`, I use `localhost/assets/imagetest.png`) and again my map uses the "default" marker.

PS: I also tried to use `|` instead of `%7C`. Also not working.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static maps are rendered on Google's servers. Google's server can't access your localhost to retrieve the marker, so it can't render it.

To be rendered the marker icon **has** to be publicly accessible.